# Angular-CLI freezes on bulding

Tags: linux, angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-2

I moved to angular-cli and have a problem during production deployment. On local PC with win10 it's all ok, but when I try to build on centos server building freezes on 10%.

**OS**: CentOS 6.6
**ng - v**:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 6.10.1
os: linux x64
@angular/common: 4.0.1
@angular/compiler: 4.0.1
@angular/core: 4.0.1
@angular/forms: 4.0.1
@angular/http: 4.0.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.1
@angular/router: 4.0.1
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.1
```

Then:

```
cd ~
ng new ngtest
cd ngtest
ng build
```

And I have this out in during 15 minutes without any changes.

```
 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active
```

Htop shows 0% of processor. And console has no reaction on Ctrl+C. Only kill -9 from other terminal can stop this.

Can someone tell me what is wrong in my confiruration? Thanks!

Comment: try running with` --verbose` maybe it'll print where exactly it's stuck. Alos make sure your local version of node matches the ci version.

Comment: With --verbose I have absolutely the same output. Local version of node 7.8.0. I've tried this version on server (it was same output), but then I read couple hints that this version has a probles with console applications and downgrade server version to 6.10.1.

Comment: did downgrading work ?

Comment: Nope. In description I've mentioned downgraded version.

Comment: It is look's like a webpack problem. I've ejected ng project and on has the same on webpack execution.

Comment: Try this, spin a centos 6.6 instance in virtual box, install node and npm and try there. See if it's a Centos 6.6 issue. Also, lookup the system logs for centos and see if there are any helpful logs there.

Comment: It's all ok on virtual box. Same uname -a. Same ng -v. But on VB works and on real machine doesn't.

Comment: so this means something is wrong with the centos server. Since you cant get any helkpful logs, the fastest option is updating the server as described here: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-updating-your-system.html. then uninstall node/npm and reinstall them, reinstall angular-cli  and try again.

Comment: Updated 431 packages. Removed @angular/cli. Removed NPM. Cleaned YUM. Reinstalled NPM. Reainstalled globally @angular/cli. ng new testng, ng build gives me same result.

Comment: at this point I'm out of options.. last thing you can try is elevate your permissions with `sudo` ie `sudo ng new app`. see if it works. This is extremely unrecommended, and is only for testing if this is a permission related issue. The only other option is to kill that centos instance and start fresh.

Comment: Installed globally webpack. Executed "webpack --verbose" - the same

Comment: I do everything under root. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: that should **not** cause issues. **If** it worked under root in **VM**, it should in your server. It's worth pointing that running apps under root is extremely unrecommended, here is an article about it: http://bencane.com/2012/02/20/why-you-should-avoid-running-applications-as-root/

Comment: It's only reboot of 2-year uptime server helped. Now building is going normally. Thank you for help!

Comment: Ah, i assumed you've done that already. Glad it worked, please answer the question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to reinstall @angular/cli
2. Try to reinstall nodejs and npm
3. Try to update all soft with yum update
4. Try to restart the server